# Struts2 Jquery Grid

Tags: jquery, struts2, grid

i have used Struts2 Jquery Grid and my grid is having some Rows in which there are some usernames , passwords and so on, if i am adding any duplicate username it is allowing me to add the duplicate username, i want to know if there is a way which will warn me that there is a user with the same username.

Comment: This question is only answerable by the S2 audience which uses, I presume some sort of jquery tag library? You'll either need to look at the documentation of the tag lib, post more information so in the off chance someone who uses the same component as you will answer or post the JS/jQuery code so the jquery audience can help you directly without needing to know any S2 details.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement, but there's no direct way of doing it, but I found something useful looking in the source code of the plugin and here is what I did.

GRID

```
 navigatorAddOptions="{
              reloadAfterSubmit:true,
              afterSubmit:function(response,postdata){
              return isError(response.responseText);
              }
              }"
```

javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function isError(text){
        //            document.getElementById("errorpara").innerHTML=text;
        if(text.indexOf('ERROR')>=0){
            return [false,text];
        }
        return [true,''];
    }
</script>
```

in struts.xml

```
 <result name="error">/x.jsp</result>
```

x.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<s:actionerror/>
<s:actionmessage/>
<s:fielderror/>
```

in the action

```
addActionError("ERROR: Username already exists!");
                return ERROR;
```

So here the add/edit dialog box of grid shows up the error.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is a business requirement you have and you need to incorporate it yourself.
You could have a constraint at table level and catch the particular constraint violation exception, to be shown on screen any way you desire.